# ¿Cómo alinear un div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<form id="formLista" class="form-group" style="align-content:center; position:center">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="margin-top: 10px"></div>
    <div class="box-primary" id="table_div" style="align-content:center; position:center"></div>
</form>
```

El div con id "table_div" lo utilizo en mi código jquery para darle formato jsgrid

```
$("#table_div").jsGrid({
   width: "80%",
   height: "auto",
   paging: true,
   center: true,
   autoload: true,
   filtering: false,
   pageSize: 10,
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que no se alinea al centro mi jsgrid, así cambie el width por auto o por 100%, se alinea hacía la derecha, no logro entender el problema.

Si alguien puede ayudarme, estaré agradecida. Saludos.

Comment: Puedes intentar meter el form en un `<div>` asignarle a una clase a dicha división y darle con css un atributo `text-align: center`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías intentar el siguiente estilo:

```
style="margin:0 auto 0 auto"
```

me ha sido útil muchas veces.

Comment: Me ha sido útil también, muchísimas gracias!!!! Saludos. @samz550a

Answer (score 0):

Las tablas no tienen esa característica. tiene que tener la opción float: letft

Hay opciones. left right y center.